# Formatting with mako

Tags: python, template-engine, mako

Anyone know how to format the length of a string with Mako?

The equivalent of *print "%20s%10s" % ("string 1", "string 2")*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use python's string formatting fairly easily in mako

```
${"%20s%10s" % ("string 1", "string 2")}
```

giving:

```
>>> from mako.template import Template
>>> Template('${"%20s%10s" % ("string 1", "string 2")}').render()
'            string 1  string 2'
```